# boolean algebra: DeMorgan's law confusion

Tags: boolean-algebra

the following function should be put into table values:
$$y = \overline{(a*b*d+c)}$$
So the first thing i am doing is using DeMorgan to get rid of the "whole-term-negation":
$$y = (\tilde a + \tilde b +\tilde d * \tilde c)$$

from here all i do is making a 4 variables truth table (4 columns, 16 rows) and set a "1" if the row equals the term.

However, i used an online tool (http://www.elektroniker-bu.de/kvdiagramm.htm) to check my solution and depending on the term i am using {~(a*b*d+c); (~a+~b+~d*~c)}, i get different results. 
Am i using De Morgan wrong?

Comment: I think you are missing parenthesis in the second expression, it should be $(\tilde a + \tilde b + \tilde d)*c$

Comment: you are right, that's what the tool does. But why the parenthesis? Is there a special rule saying so? in usual algebra 1+2+3*4 = 1+2+(3*4).

Comment: Right, if $1+2+3*4=1+2+(3*4)$, then you've misapplied DeMorgan's law, which really is best to only apply to expressions that are well-parenthesized to make sure this sort of thing doesn't happen.

Comment: If you enter into that software `~(abc+d)` you get `(~a+~b+~c) * (~d)`. So it seems to think adjacency $ab$ has precendence over $+$, but $*$ and $+$ are evaluated left-to-right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be a problem with precedence. For example, assuming $*$ is done before $+$. Then the correct application of De Morgan's law is
$$
y = \overline{(a*b*d) + c} = \overline{(a*b*d)} * \overline c
= (\overline a + \overline b + \overline d) * \overline c.
$$
This does not match
$$
(\overline a + \overline b + \overline d * \overline c) = \overline a + \overline b + (\overline d * \overline c).
$$

Comment: so is the software solution incorrect?

Comment: The software might be assuming no order of operations, just left-right application, in which case it is correct.@ChrizZz

Comment: Your formulas are probably incorrect. If you put proper parentheses, the software should say that the two formulas match. (Not that I can read German though...)

Comment: All right i think i get it! in the first part ("whole-term-negation") i should have set the parentheses before i converted with LeMogan.